# Gridview is not visible on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to display the same grid on three button click events by passing different queries in sql command.

```
                <table style="width:100%;" cellspacing="2" class="Text">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan ="2">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnreport1" runat="server"
                                     Text="Report1" Width="104px"
                                     OnClick ="btnreport1_Click1"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                         
                </table>
                            <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="True" AllowPaging="True"
                                 AllowSorting="True">
        </asp:GridView>
```

VB Code

```
Protected Sub btnreport1_Click1(sender As Object,
                        e As EventArgs) Handles btnreport1.Click
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(
                         "TERAMSConnectionString").ConnectionString)
            conn1.Open()
            Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand =
               New SqlCommand("select * from AssetsHardware_Master ,
                               Desktop where Serial_no !=SerialNo", conn1)
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
            dt.Load(dr)
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: When i am trying the same thing as a separate application its working fine and i am stuck in this from last three days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copypaste error?

your Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnreport1" runat="server" Text="Report1" Width="104px" 
            OnClick ="btnreport1_Click1"/>
```

your method declaration:

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _ 
     Handles Button1.Click
```

Your method will be never used, try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Report1" Width="104px"/>
```

or this:

```
Protected Sub btnreport1_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

Comment: Yeah thanks but even after correction it does not hit i created a new application just now it still doesn't work please help me.

Comment: Try to debug it, so you can see if the datatable is filled

Answer (score 2):

Here You Can not calling method which bind the Grid View

In Design View `OnClick ="btnreport1_Click1"`

and in Code Behind `Button1_Click()`

thats why it will not showing result in Grid view

Comment: The name doesn't matter, he's using `Handles Button1.Click`. He hasn't shown this button, however, i assume that it exists, otherwise he couldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect condition  in your `WHERE`-clause:

```
where Serial_no != SerialNo
```

This will at least return nothing because no SerialNo is `!=` itself (it's the same as `where 1=2`).

I asssume that you want to use parametrized queries:

```
Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from AssetsHardware_Master ,Desktop where Serial_no != @Serial_no", conn1)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial_no", SerialNo)
```

Here SerialNo is a variable, if it's a static string `SerialNo`:

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial_no", "SerialNo") ' presuming varchar column
```

Comment: I have tested this with simple queries likes - Select * from test -  too its working.

Comment: No,  when the same thing a try with fresh application it works but in my project its not showing up, is my vb code is fine @tim.

Answer (score 0):

I observed a problem in your code sample. You Button control ID is "btnreport1", but your button click event handler handles a non-existed control ID named "Button1.Click". In order for your event handler to handle the click event from your button, its handles clause must be changed to:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles btnreport1.Click
```

You can also make a single handler that handles many button clicks...

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles btnreport1.Click, _
    Handles btnreport2.Click, _
    Handles btnreport3.Click, _
    Handles btnreport4.Click
```

About the feature known as "AutoEventWireup"... At the top of every ASPX page, in the Page Declaration, there is an attribute called "AutoEventWireup". This is set to true or false. When using the true settings, ASP.NET automatically connects buttons and other controls to event handlers. For example, a control named "MyButton" click event would automatically get bound to an event handler names "MyButton_Click". When using the false setting, you must explicitly "wire up" buttons to event handlers using the "... Handles MyButton.Click" clause.

Whether you are using AutoEventWireup or not, your code example will never work becuase the control IDs and Handles declarations do not match.